# Ask what's needed to increase salary?

Tags: salary, human-resources, skills, raise

Suppose I'm interested in increasing my salary at work.

**Would it be a good idea to express this to HR/boss and let them tell me what THEY expect me to improve in order to deserve a promotion?**

A possible attempt: 
*"I'm interested in growing aligned with the company direction to gain further responsibilities. What could I do to achieve this goal?".*

Maybe by asking this question they'd look more carefully my quality of work and in some way pressure them to see that I'm improving in needed skills they told me, and then, as they said, deserving a raise.

**Duplicate clarification**: The possible duplicate question states that OP feels underpaid and wants to negotiate a raise. I'm not being underpaid neither I want to ask for a raise without giving value in return. I'm not negotiating, I'm trying to know if it would be a good idea to ask what they expect me to do in order to **deserve** a salary increase.

Comment: Being interested in increasing my salary doesn't necessarily imply that I'm being underpaid. It's just growing.

Comment: all the answers there are directly applicable to how you should ask for a raise.

Comment: sometimes a company can only afford so much for a specific role and you have to look outside if you are worth more than they can pay

Comment: Hi Peter, can you [edit] your question and clarify what is missing from the answers in the linked dup? This will both help answerers here provide you with the best answers and also help prevent this question from being closed. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253, done.

Answer (score 2):

That's a perfectly reasonable question to ask.  Normally, though, it is a question that you would ask of your manager not of HR.  Commonly, it is a question that you would ask your manager during an annual review process.  If you don't have a review process (or if review time is too far out and you want to get feedback more quickly), there is nothing wrong with scheduling an appointment with your boss to discuss your performance.  During your review (or during the meeting you request), you would generally want to get feedback from your manager about what you're doing well and what you can improve on.  At that point, asking what you would need to do to get a raise or get a particular promotion would be very reasonable.